# Parallel HDF5 for C# / .NET

Tags: c#, .net, hdf5

I'm new to HDF5 and I plan to store datasets of several hundred megabytes. I found that it is possible to access (write/read) a hdf5 file from multiple processes. So called parallel.

Could someone tell me if the needed functions for parallel hdf5 are implemented in hdf5dotnet? Does it makes sense to use hdf5dotnet or would it be better, even if more complicated, to run C++ code within C# to use parallel hdf5?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf5-quest.html#mthread), there is a thread-safe HDF5 library for Unix. However, this implementation is not thread-efficient, so the performance gain for parallel calls will be limited. However, as you are using C# you are likely running your application on a Windows platform and currently there is no thread-safe implementation of the HDF5 library.

Comment: Isn't there written that there is a thread safe one for Windows? But if I go into the info about thread safe hdf5 it tells me that it serializes commands. Which would not lead to higher performance in parallel reading/writing. Am I right?

Comment: Python is able to do that http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/mpi.html

Or do I get something wrong?